# Solve the following ODE using the trial solution method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Question:
Solve the following ODE using the trial solution method
$$ y'' + 2y' + y = 2e^{-t} $$
$$ y(0) = 1$$
$$ y'(0) = 0 $$

Attempt:

First find the complementary function, $y_{cf} = Ce^{\lambda t} $
$$ \lambda^2 + 2\lambda + 1 = 0 $$
$$ (\lambda + 1)^2 = 0$$
$$\lambda = -1, -1$$

Thus, has complementary function of $y_{cf} = C_1e^{-t} + C_2te^{-t}$

Next to find particular integral $y_p$

Because the $y_p$ is similar to forcing function $f(t) = 2e^{-t}$ and $C_2te^{-t}$, multiply $y_p$ by $t^2$

$$y_p = bt^2e^{-t}$$
$$y''_p + 2y''_p + y_p = 2e^{-t}$$
$$bt^2e^{-t} - 4bte^{-t} + 2be^{-t} + 4bte^{-t} - 2bt^2e^{-t} +t^2e^{-t} = 2e^{-t}$$
$$ 2be^{-t} = 2e^{-t}$$
$$ b = 1$$

Thus, $y_p = t^2e^{-t}$

$$y = y_{cf} + y_p$$
$$ y = C_1e^{-t} + C_2te^{-t} + t^2e^{-t} $$

$$y(0) = C_1 = 1$$

$$ y' = -C_1e^{-1} + C_2(-te^{-t} + e^{-t}) -t^2e^{-t} + 2te^{-t}$$

$$y'(0) = -C_1 + C_2 = 0$$

$$C_2 = 1$$

Therefore, the particular solution for this ODE is:

$$y = e^{-t} + te^{-t} + t^2e^{-t}$$

Comment: we expect to need $t^2 e^{-t},$ try that first

Comment: You could use the fact that \begin{align}
y''+2y'+y&=2e^{-t}\ \ \ \ \ \ \text{is equivalent to} \\ 
(e^ty)''&=2
\end{align}

Comment: $t^2e^{-t}$ is used instead because $te^{-t}$ is similar to the $C_2te^{-\lambda t}$ from the complementary equation, so we have to multiply by another $t$?